# Spring mvc el only works when jsp in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I just learned servlet and now getting to learning Spring MVC. I just couldn't get my head wrapped around this

Normal jsp servlet I use EL to access session.attribute without putting jsp within WEB-INF, but with Spring MVC it seems like I have to put JSP file within WEB-INF for EL to work why is this? or am I just doing something wrong?

Example Servelet (Working example):

Index.jsp

```
<form id="form" action="form-el" method="POST">
        <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName">
        <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>

<div id="result>
  <p>${name}
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
public class formServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");

        String url ="/index.jsp";

        ServletContext cs = getServletContext();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
        session.setAttribute("lastName", lastName);

        cs.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Spring: (Working example)

File structure:

```
|-WebContent
    |-WEB-INF
         |-html
             -index.jsp
         - offers-dispatcher-servlet.xml
         - web.xml
```

Index.jsp

```
${name}
```

offers-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.caveofprogramming.pring.web.controllers">
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
```

public class OffersController {

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String showHome(HttpSession session){
    // Return logical name of the view to use. The actual job of figuring out
    // what view to load is something called "viewResolver"
    session.setAttribute("name", "Tim");
    return "index";
}
```

=============================

Now if I move index.jsp outside of WEB-INF and change offers-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/"></property>  <!-- Change directory -->
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

New File structure:

```
|-WebContent
    |-WEB-INF
         - offers-dispatcher-servlet.xml
         - web.xml
     -index.jsp
```

This no longer works, returns null... could someone help to explain?  Thank you.

Comment: If you located .jsp file in root of your application (`WebContent`), and changed prefix of ViewResolver, it has to work. Check did you deployment tool does copied this `index.jsp` into root of application.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your JSP outside WEB-INF is a security issue. A malicious user can open http://yoursite.com/db.jsp and get some insight on your application (worst - the database credentials) from the exception message. So always put jsp inside your WEB-INF folder

Comment: I think db will be saved in WEB-INF context.xml.  But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all WEB-INF resources are accessible to the resource loader of your Web-Application and not directly visible for the public.

if you use maven, this project as it will automatically create and fill this folders during the build of the WAR file and only visible in the produced WAR file

Answer (score 0):

No reasons to locate JSP pages outside WEB-INF folder because it's not secure. 
You can do this for you start page (*index.jsp*) or someone else static resource (css, js files).
In this case you should add resources into context file with your *viewResolver*, e.g.

```
<mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>
```

Comment: thanks but not what I am asking here... Thanks for suggestion resource. I think I did something similar but I use mapping instead.